# Is it possible to restart IIS on a Azure web role without restarting the process?

Tags: iis, azure

I have a site running on an Azure web role and I can force restart the application by  modifying the web.config but if I want to restart IIS I have been told that I should never do this manually via remote desktop and that instead I should restart the Azure hosted process.

This [article seems to agree](http://www.britishdeveloper.co.uk/2012/01/do-not-iisreset-on-azure.html) with this opinion.

My problem is that restarting a process can take nearly 10-15 minutes to restart. Is there a quicker way to achieve this?

I am currently using the windows.azure.com UI to do all deployments and management.

Comment: Why would you want to restart the IIS in first place ?

Comment: @astaykov Probably too lengthy to place in a comment, but we are using Umbraco Accelerator and there are certain actions that require a role restart and I am confident I may be able to achieve the same with a IIS restart. In addition to this we are using Examine Azure which during testing phase has been ropey, so I need to be able to restart IIS occasionally.

Comment: There are always situations where you want to do a (on instance basis) iisreset or similar.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A couple things to point out here.  When your role starts, it uses something called the IISConfigurator to call out programmatically to IIS and create apps, vdirs, app pools, etc. as defined in Service Definition.  That is done once on startup.

Remember that the w3wp.exe process that hosts your website is completely separate from the RoleEntryPoint that you might use to run code.  As such, you cannot just called RoleEntryPoint.RequestRecycle() and expect that IIS will restart (it won't).

One solution you might try if you must restart IIS is to programmatically do it.  Here is my 3 line solution for restarting IIS on Windows Azure:

```
var mgr = new ServerManager();
var azurePools = mgr.ApplicationPools.Where(p => Guid.TryParse(p.Name));
azurePools.ToList().ForEach(p => p.Recycle());
```

I am using the knowledge that application pools are GUIDs in Windows Azure to filter them down to the ones I am interested in.

Now, you just need a way to run that code from an elevated condition on demand across each instance.  That is a common problem with lots of solutions.  Perhaps have each instance poll a file or table for a signal to run that code whenever you need to restart IIS.

Comment: +1 This is good to know.  In our case, we don't have any code that runs in the RoleEntryPoint.  That's why restarting IIS works for us.  Would you recommend running the above code in a production instance?

Comment: how is this solution ANY different to iis-reset, or RDP'ing and restarting the IIS processes manually? this just does it through code.

if the article you link to is true, then this will make no difference at all. will it?

Comment: If you know that you occasionally need to reset IIS in response to normal application updates (e.g modifying CRM themes, etc.), you typically want an automated solution.  Otherwise, no, it is not altogether different.  RDP is great for troubleshooting, not so hot for longterm operations mgmt.

Comment: @jmac - it depends a bit on how you implement it.  A non-trivial implementation would roll through each instance, have it report itself busy to the load balancer, then run this code to restart (and then report back as ready).  That way you keep some instances available as you upate.  If you just shotgun the command to each instance, you will likely have a brief period while each IIS app pool recycles until it can serve again.

Answer (score 2):

Why do you need to restart the instance?  Are you experiencing a memory leak or some other problem in your production deployment?  In a production environment, the only truly safe way to restart an instance is via the Azure management portal or the Azure management REST API.

If you're working with a dev/test deployment, you can RDP in and take your instance offline using the [Set-RoleInstanceStatus](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/gg593189.aspx) PowerShell Cmdlet.  At this point you're free to run IISReset, restart the WWW publishing service, modify the web.config, copy new dlls to the bin folder, etc., etc.  We do these things all time with our dev/test instances without a problem, but we never tinker with our production instances via RDP unless we need to troubleshoot an urgent issue.

Comment: i would definitely agree here. you need to find out WHY you need to recycle your IIS processes. if you have a memory leak, then you are going to want to fix that!

Answer (score 2):

If you deploy your application as App Service "YourName" like

[image: Azure App Service]

with url http://yourname.azurewebsites.net
you should be able to connect to  http://yourname.scm.azurewebsites.net
using the same credentials as for Azure management.
At this url you find [Kudu](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki) for respective App Service.

If you select in menu Tools>Support and then select Analyze>Metrics
then you should be able to click at "Restart w3wp".

[image: Kudu UI]

Time for application to be operational again wasn't unexpectedly long for 3 applications I tested.

If you need only to "observe" w3wp then you may check https://youname.scm.azurewebsites.net/ProcessExplorer/

Answer (score 0):

you could try remote desktop to the instance and recycling IIS that way

Comment: This is exactly what I have been told that I shouldn't do - manually restart IIS.

Comment: i kinda assumed you were running in dev/test and then it really doesn't matter what you do. if the role dies as suggested in that post, then you will be forced to restart it via the Mngt Console or the API anyways.